# Searching Java ArrayList for comma-seperated values - string and int conbination.

Tags: java

First off, thanks for all you do.  I am new-ish to Java and I am creating a program to ask user for name, ticket type and fine amount.  I am taking that information and writing it to a text file (project.txt).  I am reading in the contents of the txt file using Scanner readArray and then sorting contents into a 'list' array.  I have sorted the list alphabetically and now i want to search the array for a keyword entered from user input.  The list is stored as "name, ticket type, fine (ex: mike, speeding, 250.00".  When the user inputs a name to search for (ex: mike), i am getting not found...even though mike, speed, 100.00 is in the project.txt.  I feel like it has to do with comma seperated values, however, i have to format it this way.  Code follows (please be nice!  I will clean the code up once its working...)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.text.Collator;
public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String name = "";
    String ticketType = "";
    double fine;
    char quit;
    boolean cont = true;

    while (cont){
    do {
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Project.txt", true));
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Name:");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ticket Type:");
        ticketType = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("fine:");
        fine = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("press 'q' if you are done entering or 'c' to continue entering");
        quit = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            out.print(name + ", ");
            out.print(ticketType + ", ");
            out.printf("%.2f",fine);
            out.println();
            out.close();
    }
    while (!(quit == 'q'));{
        System.out.println("done");
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("are you sure youre done");
    System.out.println("enter y to if your done, n to enter more");
    char Continue = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

    if (Continue == ('y')){
        cont = false;
        }
    //Done entering names to list
    //Now read in file to array and sort alphabetically

    }
    Scanner readArray = new Scanner(new File("Project.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (readArray.hasNext()){
        list.add(readArray.next().toLowerCase());

    }
    readArray.close();
    Collections.sort(list, Collator.getInstance()); //sort array alphabetically
    list.forEach(System.out::println); //print array as list ',' separated
    Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("search keyword: ");
    String keyword = search.next().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("searching for: " + keyword);
    if (list.contains(keyword)){
        System.out.println("found");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(" not found");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) why you making several Scanners?  2)  while loop should be  -- >while (readArray.hasNextLine()){
        list.add(readArray.nextLine().toLowerCase());

    } . I am not saying it solves your problem but at least we got somewhere now.

Comment: I believe your text contains the comma. Ex: "mike,".

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I will clean up the scanners but that isn't my problem.

Comment: Johnny, when i search for "mike," i also receive a not found output...

Comment: If your description of what you're doing is correct, then your list does not contain `"mike"`. It contains `"mike, speeding, 250.00"`.

Comment: As the default delimiter for `Scanner.next()` is white space, shouldn't the list contain 3 items: `["mike,", "speeding,", "250.00"]`? @M.Luke How many items are in the list?

Comment: However many the user inputs. It will not be more than 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arkadiy mentioned correctly, the list does not contain "mike", but rather "mike, speeding, 250.00".

A possible naive search implementation is:

```
  String keyword = search.next().toLowerCase();
  System.out.println("searching for: " + keyword);

  boolean found = false;
  for (String element : list) {
    if (element.contains(keyword)) {
      found = true;
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    System.out.println("found");
  }
  else {
    System.out.println(" not found");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only reading the next token in the file, read the whole line like this :

```
while (readArray.hasNext()){
    list.add(readArray.nextLine().toLowerCase());

}
```

Same could be said for :

```
String keyword = search.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

Arkadly is correct then if you only searching for a name:

```
while (readArray.hasNext()){
    String name = readArray.nextLine().toLowerCase().split(",")[0];

    list.add(name);

}
```

By the way the .contains for ArrayList works differently from .contains for a String. It looks for the specific element in the ArrayList :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm